# Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "src.main"

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I saw the solution is changing `main` -> `src.main` so I tried that, but the same problem is occuring even if I use `cd src` to move to src and run `uvicorn main:app --reload`, errors continue.

What do I need?

I am using a virtual environment but I tried running uvicorn without the vm and I get the same issue.

code structure

```sh
.
|__ Alembic/
|__ venv/
|__ src/
    |__ main.py
    |__ services.py
    |__ database.py
    |__ models.py
    |__ __init__.py
```

Comment: Hello @Bilal, In order for us to help you we need you to provide more details about your question: like your code structure, if you are using a venv, etc.

Comment: ok sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow

Comment: No worries and Welcome then! 
Are you using VSCode? Have you tried running it from the terminal?

Comment: Yes I am using vscode I was using the integrated terminal. I tried it from the ubuntu terminal, I get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made it work and I have no idea how. But what I did was change all the imports to module imports.

so instead of

```py
import database
```

or

```py
from . import database
```

I did:

```py
from src import database
```

or

```py
import src.database
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the VSCode Python interpreter

Try this **in this order**:

1. In the VSCode terminal, go to your project root folder

```sh
myProjectRootFolder
|__ ...
|__ venv/
|__ src/
    |__ ...
    |__ main.py
    |__ __init__.py
```

1. Activate your virtual env named `venv`

```sh
source venv/bin/activate
```

1. Install the required dependencies

```sh
pip install fastapi uvicorn
```

4. **Now!** Select the Python interpreter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (macOS: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)

[image]

5. **Deactivate** your venv (if you don't deactivate your venv, you would have the same error you mentioned before)

```sh
deactivate
```

6. **Activate** it again

```sh
source venv/bin/activate
```

7. Run your code

```sh
# if you are in the root folder
uvicorn src.main:app

# or

# if you are in the src folder
uvicorn main:app
```

Answer (score 0):

This was quite annoying for me, so just in case someone finds this question but none of the answers above can help, here is what I did.

Add the following main method to the main file of my app:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = os.getenv("PORT")
    if not port:
        port = 8080
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Then run this using python instead of running the `uvicorn` module:

```bash
python -m app.main
```

The output now was more useful:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/robert-andreidamian/Workspace/panprices/shelf-analytics-api/app/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from app.routers import auth, users, availability, data, overview
  File "/Users/robert-andreidamian/Workspace/panprices/shelf-analytics-api/app/routers/overview.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app.main import get_db
  File "/Users/robert-andreidamian/Workspace/panprices/shelf-analytics-api/app/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    app.include_router(overview.router)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'app.routers.overview' has no attribute 'router' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

As you can see the problem was generated by a circular dependency issue. I ran into this when following the SQLAlchemy tutorial in the FastAPI documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/ . As suggested, i created the `get_db` function in my main file.

Before that I had already split the router in multiple files as explained in another section of the documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/.

This resulted in a circular dependency between the main file, that was importing the routing modules, and the routing modules that were importing the `get_db` function from the main module.

Hope this saved some of your time and frustration!