# Docker Compose and FastAPI: Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "app.main"

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

**EDIT:**
I'm now thinking this is a red herring.  It turns out there were some unrelated build problems in the module (string in one spot instead of str in a file that imported the string package).  I suppose having unit tests that I could run separately to this docker container would be useful, who could have guessed.  Still though, I wish the uvicorn error was more clear.  Mods, I'd say leave this post up as module build issues will cause the same error string as the directory pointing issue referenced in the other questions.

---

I have a docker compose file that looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  backend:
    build: nfp-backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./nfp-backend:/usr/src/
....
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
├─db
├-docker-compose.yml
├─nfp-backend/
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── alembic
│   ├── README
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
├── alembic.ini
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── main.py
│   └── routers
├── requirements.txt
└── venv
├─nfp-devops
├─nfp-frontend
├─nfp-test
```

The backend dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD alembic upgrade head && uvicorn app.main:app  --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --reload-dir app --log-level debug
```

The relevant piece of main.py:

```
app = FastAPI()
```

The answers on other questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819376/fastapi-throws-an-error-error-loading-asgi-app-could-not-import-module-api) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69952385/error-loading-asgi-app-attribute-app-not-found-in-module-main) surrounding this issue center on the directory structure not matching the uvicorn command.

For me, this shouldn't be the issue as we should be trying to run the command against app/main.py, which is what I'm doing.

From my backend docker container:

```
# pwd
/usr/src
# ls
Dockerfile  README.md  alembic  alembic.ini  app  requirements.txt  venv
# ls app
__init__.py  __pycache__  converters.py  routers  main.py
```

The self-answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69398555/error-loading-asgi-app-could-not-import-module-src-main) implies that there could be an issue with imports?  I'm not an expert in python by any means, so maybe that's possible.  The error message doesn't seem to imply that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try removing the volume attribute from docker-compose temporarily and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).